# How do I automate/handle calendar/date picker in Android using Appium?

Tags: appium, mobile-automation

**I want to select dynamic date passed like as input '03 Nov 1965'**

*Id for Calendar Icon:*

```
driver.findElementById("package_name:id/btn_basic_info_date_picker").click();
```

*Id for Year:*

```
driver.findElementById("android:id/date_picker_header_year").click();
```

Comment: Hey @Raju, did you fine solution for this?

Comment: @sandeepmaaram we just made date field to text field and then it became easy to handle date using a text field.

Comment: @sandeepmaaram nope. we do not have in the requirement to make date field as a text box.